# Powershell foreach write-host as individual records

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've got the following Powershell script working which searches for an AD users last name and am not getting the foreach loop output results I'm expecting.  Server 2008 R2 Domain and Powershell v3

If I have UserA LastName1 and UserB LastName1, the results are being output like this:

Please Enter a UserName: LastName1

```
User Name:  UserB LastName1 UserA LastName1
Login Name:  UserB.LastName1 UserA.LastNam1
Year Created:  2012 2014

User Name:  UserB LastName1 UserA LastName1
Login Name:  UserA.LastName1 UserA.LastName1
Year Created:  2012 2014
```

I'm trying to output like this:

```
User Name:  UserB LastName1
Login Name:  UserB.LastName1
Year Created:  2012

User Name:  UserA LastName1
Login Name:  UserA.LastName1
Year Created:  2014
```

The script I'm using is as follows:

```
$UserName = read-host "Please Enter Users LastName"
$SAN = "*$UserName*"
$GetUser = GET-ADUSER -Filter {(SamAccountName -like $SAN) -and (enabled -ne "FALSE")}         
-Properties * | Sort-Object givenname -Descending

foreach ($FoundUser in $GetUser) 

{
write-host "User Name: " $GetUser.CN
write-host "Login Name: " $GetUser.samaccountname
write-host "Year Created: " $getUser.whencreated.year
write-host
}
```

$GetUser.CN
results in the following, so I'm trying to figure out why my write-host is producing two entries per line.

```
UserB LastName1
UserA LastName1
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `foreach` loop, you need to replace each `$GetUser` with `$FoundUser`. `$GetUser` Contains the whole list, while `$FoundUser` is the current list entry, which changes with each iteration of the loop. The way you currently have it implemented, you print the full contents of the list each iteration rather than printing only the current item.

Your updated code will look like this:

```
$UserName = read-host "Please Enter Users LastName"
$SAN = "*$UserName*"
$GetUser = GET-ADUSER -Filter {(SamAccountName -like $SAN) -and (enabled -ne "FALSE")}         
-Properties * | Sort-Object givenname -Descending

foreach ($FoundUser in $GetUser) 

{
    write-host "User Name: " $FoundUser.CN
    write-host "Login Name: " $FoundUser.samaccountname
    write-host "Year Created: " $FoundUser.whencreated.year
    write-host
}
```